# ActionSheet in Foundation 6 appears behind

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I have just started using [Foundation for apps](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps.html) and while I was using the [action sheet](http://foundation.zurb.com/apps/docs/#!/action-sheet), I have it appearing behind the elements (as shown in Figure 1). On check of the CSS, its positioning is absolute. This just means I am missing something somewhere.

[image: Action Sheet appearing behind] Figure 1: Action Sheet appearing behind

Things to note: This action sheet is in an AngularJS directive.

Code within the directive is:

```html
<zf-action-sheet id="actionSheet">
    <zf-as-button class="">
        <i class="icon-menu">Seriously Missing?</i>
    </zf-as-button>
    <zf-as-content position="bottom">
        <div class="row">
            test 123
        </div>
    </zf-as-content>
</zf-action-sheet>
```

Also note that the same action sheet is being used on the nav bar and its fine. Would appreciate anyone that can direct me in the right direction to fix this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by adding

```
overflow: visible;
```

To the container of the actionsheet as it is enclosed within a grid-block

```html
<div class="grid-block"> // Insert here
  <zf-action-sheet id="actionSheet">
    <zf-as-button class="">
        <i class="icon-menu">Seriously Missing?</i>
    </zf-as-button>
    <zf-as-content position="bottom">
        <div class="row">
            test 123
        </div>
    </zf-as-content>
  </zf-action-sheet>
</div>
```

This is after managing to find [this](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/520) that is quite hidden.